# Target sub element of This Object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

How can I get a sub element from $(this)?

So for example, how would I target a span element within the this object?

Comment: What did you try? Have you read any [documentation or tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for jQuery? Did you make any attempt to find the answer for yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$(this).find("span");
```

That will find all `span` elements that are descendants of the element referred to by `this`.

If you only care about direct children you could use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead:

```
$(this).children("span");
```

Alternatively, you could use `this` as the context to a selector:

```
$("span", this);
```

Yet another solution would be required if `this` was a jQuery object that contained a set of sibling elements (so the `span` is not a descendant). In that case, you would need [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(this).filter("span");
```